# How can I show camera in scene in Unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, boo

For a selfie option on my game, I need to create another camera (not a webcam view, but the camera that you can create by create->camera) and show it's view in a texture of a block (like in garry's mod, in projectors, you can project your view.). I searched it but I wasn't able to find a good answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pA7ZC8owaeo

I think this is what your looking for.
Render Texture - You must be using unity 5 or higher since you have to have pro for 4 and below to use it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a GameObject and add a camera component; something like this:

```
Camera cam = new GameObject("Selfie cam").AddComponent<Camera>();
```

Comment: You got me wrong. I mean showing sth like this (http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--wS17hM1O--/c_fit,fl_progressive,q_80,w_636/fx2lfx2iv2yfnwswcz5g.jpg) on a block like a texture.